# The Alshich and Lavan

Tags: rabbis, mysticism-kabbalah, agada-stories-legends, sheker-false, vayeitzei

There are many sources online mentioning the story of how the Alshich once gave a Drasha and the Arizal was present. In the Drasha he elaborated on the 100 different ways Lavan deceived Yaakov. At one point the Arizal started laughing. Later he explained that Lavan had been listening to the Drasha, tacitly admitting to each accusation, but had protested one of the Alshich's accusations. The Arizal said that Lavan was, in fact guilty, however he still had a bit of shame left.

http://mytorah.blogspot.com/2006/12/alshich-on-lavans-100-tricks.html

http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/aram/archives/vayetze60.htm

Does anyone know of the original source of this story?

Comment: I've also heard it on an mp3 by Rabbi Breitowitz (I believe it's sold by Ohr Sameach). But that doesn't answer your question ...

Comment: I also looked on all the Hebrew articles regarding this story and none of them have a source other than saying "there is this famous story about the Alshich".

Comment: Interestingly, [this parshah sheet](http://www.ladaat.net/siteimages/fl_4ed77764324e6.pdf) has a different version of the story: the Alshich at first couldn't think of what the hundredth was, then when he did Lavan denied that that was it, "but if I had known of it I would have done it."

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=40267&st=%u05DC%u05D1%u05DF%20%u05DE%u05D0%u05D4

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not sure if it's there, just I searched the word "Lavan Meah" and I'm not good with Ktav Rashi so if you want to search...

Comment: The way that I heard it, the reason why the Arizal was laughing was because the Alshich had mentioned a swindle that Lavan had not thought of, and Lavan had muttered "Rats, I didn't think of that one!".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This story is mentioned in the name of the Munkatcher Rebbe in the Wagschal edition of the Alshich's Toras Moshe to Bereishis (pg. 15) and in Toldos HaAri HaQadosh (pg. 27, last paragraph). I can't find earlier sources for this.